# How to check if the date is in the past in PHP?

Tags: php

my date format is:  Jan-21-2016
I want to check if it is in the past or not in PHP.
How can I do it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using `strtotime()`:

```
if(strtotime($date)<strtotime("today")){
    echo "past";
} elseif(strtotime($date)==strtotime("today")){
    echo "today";
} else {
    echo "future";
}
```

Comment: It works. Thank you very much.

Comment: Isn't `time()` simpler than `strtotime("today")`?

Comment: @TRiG, `time()` would give the current date and **time**, but `strtotime('Jan-21-2016')` would give the date at midnight of that day. This will cause of issue for the `today` case.